# How do i change the background color of theCombineTemperatureChart in codename one charts

Tags: graph, codenameone

How do i change the black background color to transparent as sown below

[image]

Comment: Did you try `getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0)`?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog it didn't work

Comment: I was able to change the red color but for the black one I failed I would want it in white

Comment: The try `chart.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255); chart.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff)`

Answer (score 2):

@Shai Well finally I got a solution for the black Margin in the BarGraphs
The black color is a renderer MarginColor

this is the solution that worked for me ......

```
renderer.setMarginsColor(ColorUtil.GREEN);
```